# Number of permutations of {1, 2, . . . , n}, in which 1 and 2 are next to each other, with 1 to the left of 2

Tags: combinatorics

Let n $\geq$ 4 be an integer. Determine the number of permutations of
$\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$, in which $1$ and $2$ are next to each other, with $1$ to the left of $2$.
I can't make sense of this problem statement. The way I see it, if $n$ is an integer, then the pair $1,2$ could be formed by any pair with the form $\overline{...x_{i-2}x_{i-1}x_i1}, \overline{2y_{1}y_2y_3...}$ or a number with the form $\overline{...x_{i-2}x_{i-1}x_i12x_{i+1}x_{i+2}x_{i+3}..}$ with $x$'s and $y$'s are some mysterious digits. Can anyone explain this problem?

Comment: Total number of permutation be obviously n! if you take 1 and 2 along together and consider them 1 then there'll be (n-1) numbers and ways to arrange them will be (n-1)! since 1 will always be left to 2 therefore their positions will be fixed and the final answer won't be multiplied by 2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of "12" as a single object, say "a".  Then the problem becomes to determine the number of permutations of the n- 1 objects, "a, 3, 4, ..., n".  There are (n-1)! such permutations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement requires that we count the number of arrangements such that

- The arrangement is a permutation of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ (*i.e. it uses each and every number from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ exactly once*)
- $1$ and $2$ are adjacent, i.e. they appear right next to one another
- $1$ appears to the left of $2$

For $n=3$ the whole list is:  $123,312$

For $n=4$ the whole list is: $1234,1243,3124,4123,3412,4312$

For $n=5$ the list begins as: $12345,12354,12435,12453,\dots$ with several more yet unwritten.

---

To solve, apply multiplication principle to the following steps:

- Choose the location in the arrangement which the $1$ will occupy (*remember that you must leave enough space to the right for the $2$ to occupy as well*)
- Place the two adjacent to the right of the $1$
- From left-to-right fill in the remaining empty spaces in the arrangement with one of the remaining digits.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

1. How many places can you put $12$ in the sequence?
2. How many ways can you arrange the other $n-2$ numbers in the spaces that remain?

Comment: So I figured out two ways: 1. Regard the pair 12 as a number, then I just have to find all permutations of (n-1) numbers, which is (n-1)! 2. Regard 12 as a number, then there are (n-1) places to insert 12 into a permutation of (n-2) numbers. Then I have (n-2)!*(n-1) = (n-1)!. Is that right?

Comment: Perfect $\text{}$.